# counting primes on different scales than the normal one

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Assuming $x-y$ axes on the normal scale we can count primes using $\pi(x).$ We know that a complex function's zeros encode information about the distribution of $\pi(x),$ and that is the Riemann zeta function, $\zeta(s).$

> Does counting primes on a different scale imply that there's a complex function whose zeros encode the distribution of those primes? If so, how would you derive the complex function? Are they all just some transformation of $\zeta(s)$?

Below I've outlined two ways to count primes on two different scales:

Say you wanted to count numbers $e^p$ for $p\in \Bbb P$ less than a certain amount. You decide to count them in the following way: $f(e^2)=e^1,$ $f(e^3)=e^2,$ and $f(e^4)=e^2, f(e^5)=e^3.$

Alternatively you want to count numbers $\ln(p)$ for $p\in \Bbb P$ less than a certain amount. And you count them in the following way: $g(\ln(2))=\ln(1), g(\ln(3))=\ln(2), g(\ln(4))=\ln(2)$ and $g(\ln(5))=\ln(3).$

Comment: So then by the counting function, you mean for example $\sum_{e^{p_k}\le n}e^k$? Because I believe that's just $\frac{e^{\pi(n)+1}-1}{e-1}$.

Comment: You might google around, or search this site, to see whether "Explicit Formulas" in an extended sense (Guinand, Weil, e.g., see Iwaniec-Kowalski) might be what you want.

Comment: @Mastrem no that's much different than what you get when plotting my example

Comment: @geocalc33 Yeah, I made a mistake. It's supposed to be $\frac{e^{\pi(\ln n)+1}-1}{e-1}$